# Adding an $('input[name="searchsongaddmore[]"]') causes AJAX to break

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in which when I call it like this it works fine and AJAX fires and I can return the `data` and alert it.

**jquery that works**

```
$(".loginFormAddMoreSetlist").submit(function () {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/addmoresetlist.php?",
        data:({id: id}),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason when I change it by adding `var searchsongaddmore = $('input[name="searchsongaddmore[]"]');` it breaks the AJAX and it actually goes to the addmoresetlist.php file

**jquery that does not work**

```
$(".loginFormAddMoreSetlist").submit(function () {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var searchsongaddmore = $('input[name="searchsongaddmore[]"]');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/addmoresetlist.php?",
        data:({id: id, searchsongaddmore: searchsongaddmore}),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

This form allows users to add more fields as they need so it gets an array from them. It looks like this

[image: add more fields]

```
<form class="loginFormAddMoreSetlist" id="<?=$row1[0]?>" action="../includes/addmoresetlist.php">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group form-group-options col-xs-11 col-sm-8 col-md-7">
        <div class="input-group input-group-option col-xs-12" id="searchsongcontainer">
            <input class="form-control searchsong" name="searchsongaddmore[]" id="searchsongaddmore" type="text" placeholder="Type Something" />
            <input class="form-control searchsonghidden" name="searchsonghidden[]" id="searchsonghidden" type="hidden" />
            <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-remove">
                <span class="fa fa-remove fa-sm"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Update</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why would you pass a whole jQuery object to your request?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? Was my suggestion able to guide you in the right direction at all?

Answer (score 1):

You're likely trying to access your `<input />` value. Try the following using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
var searchsongaddmore = $('input[name="searchsongaddmore[]"]').val();
```